# Python Nested Lists help please

Tags: python, list

```
def get_grades(grades: List[list]) -> int:
    """Return the name of the student that has the highest grade.
    If there is a tie for the highest grade, it should return the name that appears
    first in grades."""
```

My data set is a list of lists e.g.

```
GRADES = [['Todd', 'Biology', 67, 5], ['Ben', 'Chemistry', '88', 7]]
```

Here, the grade lies at index 2 of each sublist.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is there any way you can get the data in a different form?

Comment: is it 67.004 or 67,004 ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial, or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: possible dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748916/find-maximum-value-and-index-in-a-python-list and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list

Comment: Create a *placeholder* for the person with the highest grade and fill it with a  fake *person* with a grade of zero; iterate over your list; for each *person* in the list check to see if the grade is greater than the placeholder's grade; if it is, assign the *person* to the placeholder.

Comment: Please show us your attempts so far...

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
lst=[['susan', 'adams' , 67, 004], ['garret', 'jimmy', 88, 9]]
max(lst, key=lambda i: i[2])[0]
```

output

```
>>> lst=[['susan', 'adams' , 67, 004], ['garret', 'jimmy', 50, 9]]
>>> max(lst, key=lambda i: i[2])[0]
'susan'
```

---

The built-in function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) can take a key-function argument to help it make its *decision*. It works the same as a sorting key-function as described in the [Sorting How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: I think the grade is `i[2]`.

Comment: Yes , changed now

Comment: @DanielTrugman , i have indexed `[0]` and it returns only name

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of all the names that got the highest grade:

```
info = [['susan', 'adams' , 67, 4], ['garret', 'jimmy', 88, 9], ['stack', 'overflow', 88, 11]]
max_grade = max(person[2] for person in info)
max_persons = [person[0] for person in info if person[2] == max_grade]
```

If `info` is not an empty list, `max_persons[0]` will always contains a name of one of those who got the highest grade

Comment: Maybe *unwind* the generator expression and the list comprehension to make it easier for the OP .