# Python confusion toward class instance

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, instance

[Class of players that accept a list then proceed to find the player with the highest score.]

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def best_score(list):
        i = 0

        while i < len(list):

            n = list[i]         #list[1] = (Bratt, 250)             #list[2] = Lisa 150
            s = list[i].score       #list 1. score = 250                #list[2].score = 150
            ace = list[0]           #homer 50                           #homer 50
            hs = 0

            if s > hs:          #if s(250>0):                       #if s(list[2].score) > hs(250): nothing suppsoed to happen
                ace = n         #ace(homer) = n(list1) aka bratt        #ace(bratt) != n because above
                hs = s          #hs(0) = s(list1) = 250             #hs(250) != list[2]150
                                #hs is now 250
            i += 1

        return ace

p1 = Player('Homer', 50) 
p2 = Player('Bart', 250) 
p3 = Player('Lisa', 150)

ls = [p1, p2, p3] 
best = Player.best_score(ls)

msg = '{} has the best score, with {} points!'.format(best.name, best.score) 
print(msg)  # Bart has the best score, with 250 points!
```

For some reasons, my code does not return the highest player score and name. Instead, it gives me the latest player score and name instead.
    I have tried checking it by going through the loop and it still does not make sense where did I go wrong.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please don't show your code as an image, instead provide a [mcve] by **edit**ing your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find maximum value and index in a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748916/find-maximum-value-and-index-in-a-python-list)

Comment: You have to define `hs = 0` before the `while` loop to keep, because `hs` is defined at each iteration of the loop. And you probably don't need to use a loop to find the best score, see the link above.

Comment: Hi, I just moved both ace and hs before the loop and it worked!! What do you mean by "for the while loop to keep"?  
I thought if I put it at the start of the loop then the loop would go over it first and then use it down below, isn't it the same as putting it before the loop?
Thank you for your answer dude!

Comment: I forgot some words in my previous comment. You have to define `hs = 0` before the `while` loop to keep its value between iterations. With the code in the question, `s > hs` is always true because it defines `hs = 0` at each iteration.

Comment: OOOHHH I get it, Thank you sooo much!!

Answer (score 0):

We can focus on this part of the code:

```
while i < len(list):
    hs = 0

    if s > hs:
        ace = n
        hs = s
```

As it's written, `s > hs` is the same as `s > 0`, so the condition will be true for all items of the list that have a score greater than zero.

To keep the greatest value, it should be defined once before entering the loop, like this:

```
hs = 0

while i < len(list):
    if s > hs:
        ace = n
        hs = s
```

With this change, the value of `hs` will be keep during iterations of the `while` loop, and in the end it will keep the best score as `hs`.