# Need to find second maximum number in the list. All the details pasted below in the body. Please assist

Tags: python

Need to `print` second Maximum Number in a given `List`
Description - Given a `list` of numbers, find the second largest number in the `list`.

**Note:-** There might be repeated numbers in the `list`. If there is only one number present in the `list`, return 'not present'.

I have tried to directly sort it but not able to make the not present condition

Comment: You can get some idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748916/find-maximum-value-and-index-in-a-python-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy implementation would be to do something like:

```py
if len(set(input)) == 1:
   print('not present')
else:
   sorted(set(input))[-2]
```

Take a look at [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time) for other implementations.

Comment: thanks but how to add the 'not present' part for the Note part pasted below? 
Note: There might be repeated numbers in the list. If there is only one number present in the list, return 'not present'.

Comment: My apologies, fixed.

Comment: thanks.
for code:
if len(set(input_list)) == 1:
   print('not present')
else:
   s=sorted(input_list)[-2]
   print(s)

test case below is failing:
Input
[3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2]
Solution output
5
Expected output
4

Comment: I just tested and works fine. (Use a set to remove duplicated values)

Comment: Thanks keivan. I need more of your help. Can you share your mail id?

Comment: It would be a better idea to post your question on Stackoverflow, so others can use it as well.